# Return View from Asp.Net MVC 4 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

As I am working on `Asp.Net MVC 4 Web API`, I also need to return a *View on specific condition*. My flow is as given below:

1. Third party application will call my Web API method. (e.g. User Authentication)
2. If there is a valid Credential, I need to return HTTP status as a SUCCESS (200)
3. If user is Invalid, I need to return a VIEW (Login View) from the same MVC application to ask for Credential. (in the view there will be a 'Register' link)

So the point is, Is this possible to return both the `LOGIN View (html)` and a `WebResponse Status (200)` on different condition *by the same WEB API method?*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be better off returning a result with a redirect url to your view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do two things:

1. Use `AuthorizeAttribute` like in Jon Galloway's tutorial: [Getting started with WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api/videos/getting-started/authorization)
2. Wrap Your response data in `HttpResponseMessage` and redirect user if needed. For example:

   ```
   var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage<Stock>(null, HttpStatusCode.RedirectMethod);
   responseMessage.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.mysite.com/login");

   return responseMessage;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to, provided your method's return type is `ActionResult`.  After all, Web API just derives from Controller.  The bigger question though: can your client handle such varried answers to the same question?  Perhaps you should return 200 on success and non-200 on "go ask the other method for the view".